# Read EC public key from .pem file in C

Tags: c, openssl, public-key, elliptic-curve

I generated a EC public and private key pair using:

```
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out ecprikey.pem
openssl ec -in ecprikey.pem -pubout -out ecpubkey.pem
```

I want to read the public key into a byte array in C. How do I go about it? Just read from the file? Or does OpenSSL provide something? THank you!

Comment: Why do you want to read the key? Just storing it? Using it to encrypt/sign?

Comment: to encrypt a random number that i am generating

Answer (score 3):

> I want to read the public key into a byte array in C...

Well, the key on disk is likely PEM encoded. Because its a public key, it probably has the pre- and post- encapsulated boundaries of `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`. You can read it like that using standard library functions.

You can also read the public key with [`PEM_read_PUBKEY`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html). The function returns a `EVP_PKEY*`. I believe you can convert the `EVP_PKEY*` to a `EC_KEY*` with:

```
EC_KEY* ecKey = EVP_PKEY_get1_EC_KEY(pKey);
```

The `get1` above means the reference count on the key was bumped (as opposed to `get0`). Be sure to call `EC_KEY_free` when done with it.

I'm not sure how you would read the public key into an array given a `EVP_PKEY*` or `EC_KEY*`. At minimum, there are two pieces of information: the curve (like `secp256k1`) and the public element (a point on the curve, which consists of an `(x,y)` coordinate). If the named curve (i.e., the OID) is *not* present (i.e., the absence of the `OPENSSL_EC_NAMED_CURVE` flag), then you have all the domain parameters like `p`, `a`, `b`, `G`, etc. Perhaps you should look at an ASN.1/DER encoding. I think that's the closet you are going to get.

Comment: Hi, is there a code sample (or could you provide one) on how to load the public key having the named curve and the Q point? It is what I have :)

Comment: @FrizzTheSnail  - see [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Update to link for [`PEM_read_PUBKEY`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/PEM_read_PUBKEY.html).